# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx$ integrating around keyhole contour

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The idea is to prove the following by integrating $f(z)=\frac{z^a\log(z)}{z^2+b^2}$ around the contour of the figure.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos^2(\pi a/2)}\Bigg[\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi a}{2}\Big)+\log(b)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi a}{2}\Big)  \Bigg], -1<a<1; b>0$$
[image: Keyhole contour]

My try:
$$\operatorname{Res}[f(z),ib]=\frac{e^{i\pi a /2}}{2i}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$$
$$\operatorname{Res}[f(z),-ib]=-\frac{e^{i3\pi a /2}}{2i}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{3\pi}{2}\big)$$

I already proved that both $\int_{C_r}$ and $\int_{C_R}$ $\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 0$ and $R\rightarrow \infty$ respectively.
Then I came up with

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2}dx-e^{i2\pi a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2}dx -i2\pi e^{i2\pi a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2} dx =2\pi i \sum\operatorname{Res} $$

And using a previous result from another exercise:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2} dx=\frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)}$$

I've got the following not-so-friendly expression that has kept me in check for a while trying to simplify it:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx-e^{i2\pi a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx-i2\pi e^{i2\pi a}\frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)}=2\pi i \Big(\frac{e^{i\pi a /2}}{2i}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)-\frac{e^{i3\pi a /2}}{2i}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{3\pi}{2}\big)\Big) $$

So my question is, am I forgeting something real trivial here? a step that would make my solution flow smoother from what I already got? Am I overcomplicating myself somewhere? Considering that the problem is meant to be solved with the given keyhole contour (I already tried using a semicircular contour instead), any sugestion or some insight will be appreciated.

---

Exercise 9, section 4.5 from William R. Derrick, Complex Analysis and Applications.

Comment: Surely easier if you already know $\int \frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2}$: just differentiate with respect to $a$ will immediately give you $\int\frac{x^a\log x}{x^2+b^2}$.

Comment: Add some $dx$'s.

Answer (score 1):

After giving this problem another try with a semicircular contour (again ☺) I finally got a valid result using residues (I also did the differentiation respect to $a$ that user10354138 mentioned, but the idea was initially solving it by using residues). So I'm posting it here for future reference and searchers.

---

Considering the semicircular contour of the figure, we integrate $f(z)=\frac{z^a log(z)}{z^2+b^2}$ considering the pole $z=ib$ is inside the contour.

[image: Semicirc contour]

Then:
$$\oint_C f(z)dz= 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}[f(z),ib]=2\pi i\frac{e^{i\pi a /2}}{2i}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)=\pi e^{i\pi a /2}b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$$

Where
$$\oint_C f(z)dz=\int_{C_1} + \int_{C_2} + \int_{C_r} + \int_{C_R}$$

It's easy to prove that $\int_{C_r} \rightarrow 0$ and $\int_{C_R} \rightarrow 0$ as $r \rightarrow 0$ and $R \rightarrow \infty$ respectively. Then, considering the segments $C_1$ and $C_2$ we have the following.

At $C_1: z=x$ with $r<x<R$ and $dz=dx$ then:
$$\int_{C_1} = \int_r^R \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx$$

At $C_2: z=xe^{i\pi}$ with $r<x<R$ and $dz=dxe^{i\pi}=-dx$ then:
$$\int_{C_2} = \int_R^r \frac{(xe^{i\pi})^a \log(xe^{i\pi})}{x^2+b^2} (-dx) = e^{i\pi a}\int_r^R \frac{x^a (\log(x)+i\pi)}{x^2+b^2} dx$$

Then we can write the contour integral as ($\lim\limits_{\begin{smallmatrix} r \to 0 & \\ R\to \infty \end{smallmatrix}}$):

$$\oint_{C} = (1+e^{i\pi a})\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx +
i\pi e^{i\pi a} \underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{x^2+b^2} dx }_{\frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)}}= \pi b^{a-1} e^{i\pi a /2}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$$

Dividing by $e^{i\pi a /2}$ both sides:

$$\underbrace{e^{-i\pi a /2}(1+e^{i\pi a})}_{2\cos(\pi a/2)}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx +
i\pi e^{i\pi a} e^{-i\pi a /2}\frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)}= \pi b^{a-1}\big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$$

$$2\cos(\pi a/2)\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx +
i e^{i\pi a /2}\frac{\pi^2 b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)}= \pi b^{a-1} \big(\log(b)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$$

After a little of algebraic manipulation we have:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx = \frac{1}{2\cos(\pi a/2)} \Big[\pi b^{a-1}\Big( \log(b) +i\frac{\pi}{2}\Big) - \frac{i\pi^2 b^{a-1}}{2} + \frac{\pi^2 b^{a-1}}{2}\tan(\pi a/2)   \Big]$$

After factorizing $\pi b^{a-1}$, canceling $i\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-i\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos(\pi a/2)} \Big[\log(b) + \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(\pi a/2)}{\cos(\pi a/2)}   \Big]$$

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a \log(x)}{x^2+b^2} dx = \frac{\pi b^{a-1}}{2\cos^2(\pi a/2)} \Big[\log(b)\cos(\frac{\pi a}{2}) + \frac{\pi}{2}\sin(\frac{\pi a}{2})  \Big]$$

which is the desired result.